# Jquery function problem

Tags: jquery

I have this javascript code

```
var nieuwsbrief_formulier_open = false;
$("#footer a.twitter").hover(

function()
{                   
    if(nieuwsbrief_formulier_open == false)
    {
        nieuwsbrief_formulier_open = true;
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('actief');
        $("#twitter").fadeIn(600);
    }
    else
    {
        nieuwsbrief_formulier_open = false;
        $(this).parent('li').removeClass('actief');
        $("#twitter").fadeOut(600);
    }
    return false;
});
```

When i going with the mouse over the #footer a.twitter div. The #twitter div show. But when i going off this #footer .a.twitter div. Then the #twitter div going off. But i want, that the twitter div come with the hover. And when i going with the mouse over this #twitter div. that the div not going away. How can i make that?

Answer (score 0):

hover requires 2 function arguments:

```
var nieuwsbrief_formulier_open = false;
$("#footer a.twitter").hover(

function()
{                   
        nieuwsbrief_formulier_open = true;
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('actief');
        $("#twitter").fadeIn(600);
}, 
function()
{
        nieuwsbrief_formulier_open = false;
        $(this).parent('li').removeClass('actief');
        $("#twitter").fadeOut(600);
});
```